# How to configure custom background DOM for featherlight?

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

Documentation says:

> You can provide the wrapping DOM. This is a bit tricky and just for the advanced users. It's recommended to study the plugin code. But you need to provide an element with a "{namespace}-close" class: the content of the lightbox will be added after this element.

As there only is one plugin (FeatherlightGallery) which doesn't seem to alter this part of the configuration, I just tried to stick to the "class"-part.

So my config object is the following (according to the setup in featherlight source code):

```
{
    background: $([
      '<div class="featherlight">',
        '<div class="featherlight-content">',
          '<span class="featherlight-close custom-class"></span>',
        '</div>',
      '</div>'].join(''))
}
```

This works in so far, as my code is really used for the lightbox. But the lightbox content is not inserted after the element with the "{namespace}-close" class.

Can someone please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the documentation was outdated. It now reads:

You can provide the wrapping DOM. This is a bit tricky and just for the advanced users. It's recommended to study the plugin code. But you need to provide an element with a "{namespace}-inner" class: the content of the lightbox will replace this element. It is recommended that instead of providing this option you modify the lightbox on `beforeOpen` or `afterOpen`.